# Confidence interval using Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, confidence-interval

$X_1,...,X_n$ is a sample, $X_1 = ξ + η$, where $ξ,η$ are independent random variables, $ξ ∼ R[0,θ], η ∼ Bin(1,θ)$. I want to establish a confidence interval for $θ$ confidence level $1−α$ using Chebyshev's inequality. Problem is that after calculation $D(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i) = \frac{1}{n}(\frac{\theta^2}{12} - \theta^2+\theta)$ and applying Chebyshev's inequality $P(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - \frac{3\theta}{2}| \geq \frac{3\epsilon}{2}) < \frac{\frac{\theta^2}{12} - \theta^2+\theta}{n\epsilon^2\frac{9}{4}}$ on the rigth handside we have that the variance contains not only $\theta^2$, but also the multiplier $\theta$, which does not allow us to calculate the confidence interval. I also tried to find another estimation, but didn't find anything good. I'm confused about this problem and how to approach it, could anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: What do $ξ ∼ R[0,θ]$ and $D(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)$ stand for?  A uniform distribution on the interval and variance?

Comment: @Henry $R[0, \theta]$ stand for uniform distribution and $D(..)$ stands for $Var(..)$

Comment: Note that $\theta - 11\theta^2/12$ is a bounded map over $[0,1]$, so you can replace this in your bound by it's maximum possible value, and just work with that confidence interval.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you!

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality looks a strange thing to use here as the distribution and values you see give a lot of information.  Clearly $0 \le \theta \le 1$ as it is the parameter of a binomial distribution.  Almost surely $\zeta_i = X_i-\lfloor X_i\rfloor$ and so $\max_i \left(X_i-\lfloor X_i\rfloor\right) \le \theta\le 1$ with probability $1$ and in many cases this will be tighter than what a $1-\alpha$ confidence interval using Chebyshev's inequality would give you.  You could improve this interval further by looking at the values of $\eta_i = \lfloor X_i\rfloor$.